# Normalize ratio metric

Tags: analysis, functions

I have two values: one raw value number $r$ and one predicted value number $p$.

Now I want to give a metric how similar the two are on a scale from 0 to 1.

In the best case the $r=p$ which I would give a score of 1.

I first thought of defining a metric by $\frac{p}{r}$. This has the problem that if $p$ is larger then $r$ the metric generates values larger than 1. However I am a bit clueless how to normalize this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fairly standard practice to begin such a process by defining the error $\epsilon$ between $p$ and $r$ as the absolute value of their difference: $\epsilon = |r-p|$.

The next step is to consider whether a relative error is perhaps more appropriate than the absolute error. For example, when $p$ becomes a factor $10$ larger, it is reasonable to assume that the same is true for $r$ and $\epsilon$. A safe and sensible choice for the relative error might be $\epsilon = |r-p|/p$. But the denominator could also be $r$ or $(p+r)/2$ or $\sqrt{pr}$ or something similar.

If you are happy with your (absolute or relative) error, you can convert into a metric of your choice. You say that would like $m=1$ when $r=p$ and around zero if $r$ and $p$ are very dissimilar. Okay, then $m = 1 - \epsilon$ might work for you. You may also consider $m = exp(-\epsilon)$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. This was exactly what I wanted. I thought way to complicated!

Comment: You are most welcome. I am glad I could help you out.